# Websites routinely fail to distribute licenses for included software packages, should I?

Tags: internet, licensing, open-source-software

I'm building a website using Next.js, using tons of npm packages in the process. I'm verifying that none of these packages use GPL or other licenses that would require me to publish my own source code.

However, almost all of the packages I'm using are licensed under BSD or MIT or similar licenses, which require distributing the license along with any software distribution that uses the package. I actually wrote a "Legal" page for my website already that displays all the licenses of packages that I use in my website.

However, I can't see any major site that has a similar listing of software licenses. E.g., looking at cal.com's package.json for their web app: https://github.com/calcom/cal.com/blob/main/apps/web/package.json . They explicitly list dozens of dependencies, yet I fail to see how the licenses going along with all these packages are served on cal.com . Does anyone actually care about distributing licenses along with web applications?

Comment: Yes, since especially for modern JavaScript applications, parts of the source code of  included packages will be sent to the client's browser to be executed there. Notably front-end components such as Material UI

Comment: I should note that in modern web applications, unless you're doing some specific analysis, it's not straightforward to figure out what parts of the packages you're using will be sent to clients. A reasonable assumption is that parts of all software packages you're including MIGHT be sent to clients. Yet I fail to see any large web applications that account for this, and nobody seems to care.

Comment: I think the closure is unnecessary. This question could easily be rephrased in a more general manner, without referring to me specifically. Sorry for not reading the whole meta on this sub before posting. I think you're making a mistake by closing questions that are clearly interesting to a very large number of users.

Answer (score -3):

### A website doesn’t distribute software

Typically. GitHub being a notable exception.

*Using* software to make you website go is not *distributing* software.

Comment: Every website distributes software. Right click on this site here and click "view source" (in chrome) or hit Ctrl-U (in chrome)

Comment: Nearly all websites deliver copyright-covered third party material to the visitor's web browser. This usually involves JavaScript software, e.g. jQuery or NPM packages. This software is typically licensed to the website operator under terms that requires the license notice to be provided with all copies of the software. Before being served via a website, such packages are typically compressed (bundled, minified), which usually removes any attribution notices they might otherwise contain.